# Get Element By id or Name in Curl

Tags: php, curl, element

My target site contains code like this

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="suggest" value="www.google.com">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

I Get this page with Curl Php

```
<?php
$url="http://mysite.com"; 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch); 
echo $result;  
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

How can I get an element value using id or name? For example "www.google.com" in input name="suggest". Thanks for helping me.

I cant use this code for remote like this :

```
<?php
require 'Path/QueryPath.php';
qp('http://hipfile.com/bbgfom5ej9tm/zakhme_shaneie_haava_dvdrip.wmv.html/')-
```

> find('[password="login"]')->writeHTML();
>       ?>

and return this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'QueryPathParseException' with message 'DOMDocument::load() [domdocument.load]: AttValue: " or ' expected in http://hipfile.com/bbgfom5ej9tm/zakhme_shaneie_haava_dvdrip.wmv.html/, line: 18 (C:\xampplite\htdocs\test1\Path\QueryPath.php: 2106)' in C:\xampplite\htdocs\test1\Path\QueryPath.php:2346 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: QueryPathParseException::initializeFromError(2, 'DOMDocument::lo...', 'C:\xampplite\ht...', 2106, Array) #1 C:\xampplite\htdocs\test1\Path\QueryPath.php(2106): DOMDocument->load('http://hipfile....', 0) #2 C:\xampplite\htdocs\test1\Path\QueryPath.php(179): QueryPath->parseXMLFile('http://hipfile....', NULL, NULL) #3 C:\xampplite\htdocs\test1\Path\QueryPath.php(23): QueryPath->__construct('http://hipfile....', NULL, Array) #4 C:\xampplite\htdocs\test1\index.php(3): qp('http://hipfile....') #5 {main} thrown in C:\xampplite\htdocs\test1\Path\QueryPath.php on line 2346

Can help me? I used two DOM And simplehtmldom but not working for me . it works for local page only.

Comment: This could be useful: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: QueryPath is the new simplehtmldom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to use a DOM parser. Lately I've been using Query Path: http://querypath.org/

```
qp($result)->find('[name="name"]');
```

Comment: try and return error = Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'QueryPathParseException' with message 'DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile()

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php

$url="http://mysite.com"; 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch); 
echo $result;  
curl_close($ch);

// include simple_html_dom class here
// which can be downloaded from http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

$oDom = new simple_html_dom();
$oDom->load($result);
$textFieldValue = $oDom->find('[name="suggest"]',0)->value;
echo $textFieldValue; // will return www.google.com

?>
```

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'simple_html_dom' not found in C:\xampplite\htdocs\test1\index.php on line 40 how i find this class?

Comment: Visit http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ and download the class which can be found under "Download & Documents". Include it in your script

Comment: thanks. but i cant include which part i include? download pack but i dont know

Comment: put simple_html_dom.php in the same directory and include with -> include 'simple_html_dom.php';

Comment: try this code but show only page no any thing =include("dom.php");
$url="http://hipfile.com/zqgrhitohhuo/Hawaii.Five-0.2010.S02E22.720p.HDTV.X264-DIMENSION.mkv.html"; 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch); 
echo $result;  
curl_close($ch);

// include simple_html_dom class here
// which can be downloaded from http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

$oDom = new simple_html_dom();
$oDom->load($result);
$textFieldValue = $oDom->find('[name="rand"]',0)->value;
echo $textFieldValue; // will return www.google.com =